# PHP - CI 3 - Form - Setting a lot of callback validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Using Code Igniter 3, I wonder if there is a way to set multiple callback on a form->set_rule() field.

I know we can set different CI already set form_validation like this : `trim|required`. But when I tried to set mine and then, call like this, only one of them is charged.

For instance, I want to check if a number filled is out of range or not to insert it in database.

```
class MyClass
{
    public function index()
    {
        // my code here
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('iMyNumber', 'Number', 'callback_isUpperThan|callback_isLowerThan');
    }
    
    protected function isUpperThan()
    {
        return (my test) ? true : false;
    }

    protected function isLowerThan()
    {
        return (my test) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

If you have any idea to solve it, I'm all ears.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if it will work if you add a set_message in your own validation? like this

```
protected function isUpperThan()
{
    if( my test ) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('isUpperThan', 'Error Message' )
    }
    
    return (my test) ? true : false;
}



protected function isLowerThan()
{
    if( my test ) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('isLowerThan', 'Error Message' )
    }
    
    return (my test) ? true : false;
}
```